# Changing the direction of integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to change the direction of the integral:

$$ \int_0^1 dy \int_{0.5y^2}^{\sqrt{3-y^2}} fdx$$

From what I know, I first need to find the shapes:

$0.5y^2 = x$ and $\sqrt{3-y^2} =x$

Shape I is a parabola: $y^2 = 2x$
Shape II is a circle $x^2 + y^2 = 3$ (radius of $\sqrt{3}$)

So we basically draw horizontal arrows from the parabola to the circle while we keep $0 \leq y \leq 1$.

Something that looks very similar to this picture:

[image]

We need to draw vertical lines, so it looks like this, but we have 3 areas:

1. Where we hit the parabola (red)
2. Where we hit the line $y=1$ (green)
3. Where we hit the circle (blue)

[image]

And so my final answer is:

$$ \int_0^{0.5} dx \int_0^{\sqrt{2x}} fdy + \int_{0.5}^{\sqrt{2}} dx \int_0^1 fdy + \int_{\sqrt{2}}^{\sqrt{3}} dx \int_0^{\sqrt{3-x^2}} fdy$$

Am I right so far? If I am not, then how do I fix it? I feel stuck as I have no idea how to keep going... I would appreciate your help!
Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to split up the interval $[0,2]$ into three sub-intervals.

Comment: @AnginaSeng Why this interval and not $[0, \sqrt{3}]$ ? I thought my $x$ goes from $[0,0.5]$ then $[0.5 , \sqrt{2}]$ and then $[\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}]$ ...

Comment: Do we know what is $f$?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh We don't know what is $f$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is correct. You are done.

Checking of your working, $y=1$ intersect $0.5y^2=x$ at $x=0.5$. (this corresponds to  the orange region. $0.5y^2=x$ is equivalent to $y=\sqrt{2x}$ when $y>0$.

Also, $y=1$ intersect $\sqrt{3-y^2}=x$ at $x=\sqrt2$. $\sqrt{3-y^2}=x$ is equivalet to $y=\sqrt{3-x^2}$ when $y>0$.

The lower boundary is always $y=0$.

You can also express it compactly as

$$\int_0^{\sqrt3}\, dx \int_0^{\min(\sqrt{2x}, 1, \sqrt{3-x^2})}f\, dy$$

The further evaluation depends on the detail of $f$. One of the possible motivation of performing change of order of integral is that the form of $f$ is easier to integrate in a certain order.

Remark: Depending on your communitivy, some write it as

$$\int_0^{\sqrt3} \int_0^{\min(\sqrt{2x}, 1, \sqrt{3-x^2})}f\, dy \, dx$$